# Filtering Phone number

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a column that contains phone numbers in python. In that column, I want to get all phone numbers that start with +61. Could you please help me with that?

The sample data is below?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to provide your sample data. Please also include any code you've tried so far.

Comment: Please always provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) (`^[+]61`):

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Number" : ["+61 123456789", "+1 1234567890", "+41 123456789"],
    "Country" : ["Australia", "Canada", "Switzerland"],
})

regex = "^[+]61"

result = df[df.Number.str.contains(regex)]

print(result)
```

```py
          Number    Country
0  +61 123456789  Australia
```

---

Or as FionaHeJiang suggested, you should be able to use [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html). It works for me with my test data:

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Number" : ["+61 123456789", "+1 1234567890", "+41 123456789"],
    "Country" : ["Australia", "Canada", "Switzerland"],
})

print(df[df["Number"].str.startswith("+61")])
```

```py
          Number    Country
0  +61 123456789  Australia
```

---

If this does not work for you, you will need to provide some test data and more information so we can help you. Please always provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.startswith`, for example:

`df[df['phone number'].str.startswith('+61')]`

Comment: I tried this one. but I got the error:

Comment: ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: Have you checked if you have NaN in the column? If you like to ignore NaN, you could use df[df['phone number'].str.startswith('+61', na=False)]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative of startswith would be using regex module
You can use **regex module** with different types of match-making.

```
import re
df[re.findall(r'\+61.*',str(df['phone number']))]
```